# Why python for loop is working faster than two pointer approach for finding max element in list but in while loop two pointer approach is faster?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I recently started learning DSA and I came across the idea of **using two pointers to iterate our the list** so that we can **reduce the time for the iteration**, and I made this program in **python** to find max element in the **list**, which first shows the time taken by program **with using two pointer** and then it shows the time taken by program  **without using two pointer** .

and what happend to me was that when I use `while` loop for both approaches (one is checking all elements one by one and the second is using to 2 pointers to check 2 elements at the same time), the 2 pointer approach takes the less time which was I expected, But when I use `for` loop of python for checking element one by one, it's taking less time than 2 pointer approach.

So now I'm really not able to understand why this is happening, is it because `for` loop in python somehow works differently or there is something else that I did wrong in the code? I am sharing both codes below.

**with while loop:**

```
import time

arr = [x for x in range(10000000)]

# print(type(arr))
pointer_1 = 0
pointer_2 = len(arr) - 1
max = -1

start = time.time()
while (pointer_2 > pointer_1):
    if arr[pointer_1] > max:
        max = arr[pointer_1]
    
    if arr[pointer_2] > max:
        max = arr[pointer_2]
    
    pointer_1 += 1
    pointer_2 -= 1

end = time.time()

print(f"Max Number: {max}")
print(f"Runtime of the program with pointers is {end - start}")


max = 0
n = len(arr)
start = time.time()
i = 0
while (i < n):
    if arr[i] > max:
        max = arr[i]
    i += 1


end = time.time()

print(f"Max Number: {max}")
print(f"Runtime of the program is without pointers {end - start}")
```

**with for loop for  one by one approach**

```
import time

arr = [x for x in range(10000000)]

# print(type(arr))
pointer_1 = 0
pointer_2 = len(arr) - 1
max = -1

start = time.time()
while (pointer_2 > pointer_1):
    if arr[pointer_1] > max:
        max = arr[pointer_1]
    
    if arr[pointer_2] > max:
        max = arr[pointer_2]
    
    pointer_1 += 1
    pointer_2 -= 1

end = time.time()

print(f"Max Number: {max}")
print(f"Runtime of the program with pointers is {end - start}")


max = 0
n = len(arr)
start = time.time()
for e in arr:
    if e > max:
        max = e
        
end = time.time()

print(f"Max Number: {max}")
print(f"Runtime of the program is without pointers {end - start}")
```

any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: You seem to have re-invented the wheel. The built-in *max()* function (which you have rather inconveniently destroyed) will be faster than anything you can write in Python. Also, do you know anything about the data in your list? In the code shown it's sorted.

Comment: What perf numbers are you seeing? Conjecture because I'm not testing this: The 2-pointer approach is not faster than an iterative loop for whatever you're doing here because your problem is inherently linear to begin with (finding the max value of a list), and ripping through a sequence of addresses (iterating through a python list) is very fast due to locality of reference/cache line loads. A 2-pointer 'windowing' solution is for speeding up particular problems that might otherwise has quadratic runtimes (e.g. loop within a loop).

Comment: @Stuart yes I know the data is already sorted but that's not the issue, what I am not able to understand is why for loop works faster than the while loop.

Comment: @RohitBhati the `while` loop does 'more' work at the Python level - on every iteration you, for example, also do `i += 1` which is going to be done within Python, and `int`s are objects so you're basically saying "create a new int every iteration", and you do this _roughly_ 10M times (minus ~255 times because of CPython int interning). The `for` loop does more work at the C-level (assuming this is CPython).

Comment: @wkl With the use of `for` loop, The runtime of the program with pointers is 2.7614006996154785 and without pointers 1.5101604461669922. and for `while` loop in both, the Runtime of the program with pointers is 2.5035488605499268 and without pointers 3.7318713665008545.

Comment: @RohitBhati yes, you're seeing the effects of having more of your code being run at the Python-level. The pure `for` loop is going to be mostly operating at the C-level (again, for CPython). Your pointer code and your `while` loop have to do a lot more work at the Python-level as I said in my last comment.

Comment: @wkl oh!! now it's making more sense, thank you very much for the explanation :D